# what is the error in that code?

Tags: c++, c, string

What is the error in this code ??!!

HINT : the `sp_to_dash()` function in the following program prints a dash for each space in its string argument. That is, the string `"this is a test"` will be printed as `"this-is-a-test"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sp_to_dash( char *str);

int main(void)
{    
  sp_to_dash("this is a test");

  return 0;    
}

void sp_to_dash( char *str)    
{    
  while(*str) {    
  if(*str==' ' ) *str = '-';    
  printf("%c", *str);    
  str++;    
  }    
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to modify a string literal.

Comment: What error you are facing..??

Comment: You've tagged this question as both C and C++. Which is it? It matters because the rules are subtly different. In C, string literals have type `char [N]` but modifying them is not allowed. In C++, they have type `const char [N]` and most compilers should give you a warning.

Comment: Please try to be more expressive in a question's title; try to not use general terms like "Why this doesn't work?", but "Why does modifing the character array leads to a crash?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String literals are not modifiable. Change it this way:

```
int main(void)
{ 
  char str[] = "this is a test";
  sp_to_dash(str);

  return 0;    
}
```

Comment: @YuHao what do you mean by the function sp_to_dash did modify the string in the OP's code.

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy That's an obsolete response to a now deleted comment, never mind.

Answer (score 3):

Yu Hao's answer is very good, while I have another way to fixed it:

```
void sp_to_dash( char *str)    
{    
  while(*str) {    
  if(*str==' ' ) *str = '-';    
  printf("%c", *str);    
  str++;    
  }    
}
```

==>

```
void sp_to_dash(const char *str)    
{    
  while(*str) {    
  if(*str !=' ' )     
      printf("%c", *str);
  else
      printf("-");    
  str++;    
  }    
}
```

It also print the right string while it needn't modify the string.

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy ... tell the truth, if my answer is useful , really hope for an upvote :)

Comment: Interesting way to fix the problem. In this case, it's better to declare the parameter `str` as `const char *`.

Comment: @LidongGuo your answer was very useful to me, and YuHao answer's too.

but i wonder why it's better to declare the parameter as const char *,although i can't modify the string literal, i think it isn't important here

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a `const char*` to your function, ie `"this is a test"`. Your array is a string literal, and when seen by the compiler is placed into a special read-only section of the executable (*rodata*). In fact, so are the rest of your variables declared as *const*. The trick is just knowing your string is a `const char*` instead of just a `char*`.

Comment: That depends on the code is C or C++. In C, string literals are non-modifiable, but the type is just `char []` without `const` for historical reasons.

Comment: The string is still put in read only memory, however if you use `char[]` you get a (writable) copy of it in an array and not a pointer directly to it. Although what you say is interesting - how is it read only and not `const`?

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be in read only memory either. In C, string literals are not of type `const` is just for historical reason, but the compiler still knows where the string literals are, so there's no problem protecting them.

Comment: Technically, the C99 specification states that string literals are "not required to be modifiable...do not have type *array of const char*"